# How to remove the cancel ApplicationIconBadgeNumber from LocalNotification?

Tags: iphone, uilocalnotification

I am using LocalNotification in my app. It is working fine but once ApplicationIconBadgeNumber is set, not able to remove it from App. How to remove it?

Comment: Also accept some answer from your previous question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to set the application applicationIconBadgeNumber.
For example in the application didReceiveLocalNotification.

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notif {
    application.applicationIconBadgeNumber = notif.applicationIconBadgeNumber-1;
}
```