# iOS: App Icon Badge Will Not Go Away

Tags: iphone, ios, icons, badge

I've added a Local Notification into my app, but for some reason, the app installs with a "1" icon. Opening it and closing it doesn't seem to make it go away. I typed `application.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0;` into the app delegate, and have `localNotif.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0;` in my notification area. Does anyone know what I'm missing? Thank you!

Comment: Is the method to even update the badge count being called?  Run a simple NSLog and check.

Comment: @CodaFi I'm unsure if I even have one, sorry I'm still very new to this and learning as I go. What would that code look like?

Comment: I think this is what you need then.  Possible dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5553179/how-to-remove-the-cancel-applicationiconbadgenumber-from-localnotification

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This should work. Place it in applicationDidFinishLaunching in your app delegate file (or anywhere else, but that's a good place to test).

```
[UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0;
```

Comment: If you only want to adjust the number if the user has actually tapped on the notification then put your code into application:didReceiveLocalNotification.